# Unable to print the reverse of a user-filled partial array

Tags: c++, arrays, printing, reverse

For an assignment, we were to fill an array with user-defined characters that stops filling once the user enters a full stop ".". Part of the assignment is to print out the characters entered in the array in reverse, but what I have seems to just print nothing.
First time asking, so apologies if it's a silly question. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Function declarations
bool fillArray(char charArray[], int arraySize, int& numberUsed);
void outputInReverse(const char charArray[], int& numberUsed);

int main() {

    const int arraySize = 100;
    char charArray[arraySize] = { };
    int numberUsed = 0;

    //Function calls
    cout << "\nFILLING ARRAY....\n";
    fillArray(charArray, arraySize, numberUsed);


    cout << "\nARRAY OUTPUT....\n";
    outputInReverse(charArray, numberUsed);

}
```

```
//Function definitions
bool fillArray(char charArray[], int arraySize, int& numberUsed) {

    char inputChar;
    int index = 0;
    const char sentinel = '.';
    bool sentinelEntered = false;
    bool arrayFull = false;
    int count = 0;


    //Take user input
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        if ((!sentinelEntered)) {
            cout << "Enter up to " << arraySize << " character values. Enter full stop to end. " << "Enter char " << (i + 1) << ": " << endl;
            cin >> inputChar;
            charArray[index] = inputChar;
            //How many entries made
            numberUsed = i;
            count++;
            if ((inputChar == sentinel)) {
                sentinelEntered = true;
                cout << "Number of entries: " << (count - 1) << endl;
                return count;
            }
        }
    }
    if (numberUsed == arraySize) {
        arrayFull = true;
        return arrayFull;
    }
    return sentinelEntered;
    return count;
}
```

```
// Reverse 
void outputInReverse(const char charArray[], int& numberUsed) {
    for (int i = numberUsed; i > 0; i--) {
        cout << "Output in reverse: " << charArray[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

FILLING ARRAY....
Enter up to 100 character values. Enter full stop to end. Enter char 1:
a
Enter up to 100 character values. Enter full stop to end. Enter char 2:
b
Enter up to 100 character values. Enter full stop to end. Enter char 3:
c
Enter up to 100 character values. Enter full stop to end. Enter char 4:
d
Enter up to 100 character values. Enter full stop to end. Enter char 5:
e
Enter up to 100 character values. Enter full stop to end. Enter char 6:
.
Number of entries: 5

ARRAY OUTPUT....
Output in reverse:
Output in reverse:
Output in reverse:
Output in reverse:
Output in reverse:

Comment: Might be unrelated but: `const int arraySize = 100; char charArray[arraySize] = { };` is not valid C++. You could use `constexpr int arraySize = 100;`

Comment: What do you want `fillArray` to return? The number of elements? You can't return multiple values this way. Did you try to debug your code?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to return from fillArray(), but since its a bool type, assuming you are trying to return if the array is empty or not. Observe added comments to see corrections.

```
int main() {

const int arraySize = 100;
//corrected
char charArray[arraySize] = { NULL };
int numberUsed = 0;

//Function calls
cout << "\nFILLING ARRAY....\n";
fillArray(charArray, arraySize, numberUsed);


cout << "\nARRAY OUTPUT....\n";
outputInReverse(charArray, numberUsed);
return 0;
}

bool fillArray(char charArray[], int arraySize, int& numberUsed) {

char inputChar;
int index = 0;
const char sentinel = '.';
bool sentinelEntered = false;
bool arrayFull = false;
int count = 0;

//Take user input
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    if ((!sentinelEntered)) {
        cout << "Enter up to " << arraySize << " character values. Enter full stop to 
        end. " << "Enter char " << (i + 1) << ": " << endl;
        cin >> inputChar;
        //corrected: shifted here so before '.' can enter into array we return
        if ((inputChar == sentinel)) {
            sentinelEntered = true;
            cout << "Number of entries: " << (count) << endl;
            //correction: update numberUsed  before returning and no of 
            //elements = count
            numberUsed = i;
            return count;
        }
        //correction: array index should not be "index" but i
        charArray[i] = inputChar;
        //How many entries made
        numberUsed = i;
        count++;
    }
}
if (numberUsed == arraySize)
    return true;
return false;
}

void outputInReverse(const char charArray[], int& numberUsed) {
for (int i = numberUsed-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    cout << "Output in reverse: " << charArray[i] << endl;
}
}
```